# How to run jQuery code for devices with a viewport of less than 1000px and only on the homepage

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have the following jQuery code which I need to run only in the homepage as well as for devices with a viewport of less than 1000px. I have tried with the if statements but I keep ruining the code. I am stuck from this point on. Here is the code I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
 $(window).on('scroll', function(){ 
  var y = $(window).scrollTop();
   if( y > 0 ){ 
   $('#top').fadeIn(); 
   $('#header-space').fadeIn(); } 
 else { 
   $('#top').fadeOut(); 
   $('#header-space').fadeOut(); } 
 }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).on('scroll resize', function() { // fired on scroll or resize
        var ww = $(window).width(); // get window width
        var y = $(window).scrollTop();
        if( ww < 1000 && $('body').hasClass('home') ){
            if(y > 0) {
                $('#top').fadeIn();
                $('#header-space').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#top').fadeOut();
                $('#header-space').fadeOut();
            }
        }

    });
});
```